# screen freezing - list view in a scrollview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

i read several blogs\so\forum posts and see that there is clearly an issue with putting a ListView in a ScrollView. But somewhere i found that it should work if i put a linear layout(which as the list) in the scrollview and now it will work. below is my xml.
but the lists do not scroll up\down, its frozen...
any idea why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
            <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/listView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the xml layout and also modified the onScroll listener. It works perfectly fine now.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
lv1.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int index = firstVisibleItem;
            View v = view.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (null == v) ? 0 : v.getTop();
            Log.i("lv1","index:"+index+" top:"+top);
            lv1.setSelection(index);
            lv2.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        }

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            String sState;
            switch (scrollState) {
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
                sState = "Fling";
                break;
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
                sState = "Touch Scroll";
                break;
            case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                sState = "Idle";
                break;
            default:
                sState = "Unknown";
                break;
            }
                      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all ListView should not be inserted into the ScrollView. Putting your ListView inside the LinearLayout allows you to display it, but ScrollView eats all vertical scrolling events, so your ListView never receives any touch events.

You may want to play with [ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Answer (score 0):

put them inside

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you use Listview inside Scrollview  - Scroll freezes

```
listview.setEnabled(false);
```

### If you use Recyclerview inside Scrollview - Scroll freezes

#### Why screen freezes : Recyclerview has scroll behaviour & your trying to put into one Scrollview[Which already has the scroll behaviour]

So it confuses which scroll to follow

#### Use this code to disable scroll for recyclerview so it uses only SCROLLVIEW scrolls

```
yourScrollview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

**Note :** If you use multiple recyclerviews/listviews in same activity
you need to disable scrolls for all recyclerviews/listviews